# Cloudflare and 1and1 : SSL Redirect not loading the UI

Tags: ssl, nginx, cloudflare

I currently have my online store via 1and1(where I bought the domain) and our backend is hosted @ Linux cloud server using Nginx. We are using basic version of Cloudflare as frontend.

Now when we converted to https with the “wildcard” ssl certificate(GeoTrust), but we cannot get the redirects to work with the CloudFlare CDN. I have worked with 1and1 Support, but we have not found a resolution. I was hoping someone on the Cloudflare end may be able to help with the solution, but no response yet.

Bought the SSL certificate from 1and1(GeoTrust) and did the following configurations in nginx configuration

> ```
>     listen 443 ssl;
>     server_name abc.com;
>     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/abc.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
>     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.abc.com_private_key.key;
> ```

Website works for following conditions

- HTTP --> Cloudflare-->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)
- HTTPS -->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)

Website not working for

- HTTPS --> Cloudflare-->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I believe in case of `HTTPS --> Cloudflare-->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)`, cloudflare would be terminating SSL and expecting your Nginx to be running on port 80 without SSL and not with SSL on 443

Comment: listen 80;  listen 443 ssl; this is original configuration. Now after your comment tried removing this line  listen 443 ssl; from nginx config and activated Cloudflare, it serves only HTTP, if I tried to access HTTPS says 404

Answer (score 2):

Check the CloudFlare Crypto menu to select the proper [SSL type](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-):

In your case seems you need the Full strict:

[image]

> Full SSL (Strict): secure connection between the visitor and Cloudflare, and secure and authenticated connection between Cloudflare and your web server. You will need to have your server configured to answer HTTPS connections, with a valid SSL certificate. This certificate must be signed by a certificate  authority, have an expiration date in the future, and respond for the request domain name (hostname).